# Can Someone Point me to a good Android Source Code Example with multiple screens using buttons navigation?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to take a Visual Novel I have done once in Python and once in ActionScript 3, and now bring it to Android. In part because I have a Xoom tablet, and in part because I want to have a game like that I can play.

The "essentials" I'd like to see demonstrated are:

- Being able to put up a screen with an image, and then put a couple buttons on top of it, and based on which button is pressed, go to a different screen
- Put up a screen with a text region over it (dialogue), and if you click anywhere in the text region, the text is replaced with the next paragraph or two of text

I can see several things in the Android SDK/API that would let me do this, but there isn't anything that puts it all together that I have been able to find.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibly more helpful answer for anyone reading this question:
http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/opening-new-screen-in-android.html

Answer (score 4):

Your question reads like this:

> I am new and want to build an app that does exactly what I am thinking about in my head. Please point me to a tutorial that has done it all for me already that I can just use.

But you should be asking this instead:

> I want an app with Features A, B and C. I have read the documentation and I still cannot figure out how to make an App that does B. How should I go about implementing B?

You see, it is up to you (as the Developer) to bring all of the ideas together. That is the job. So if you want for something that "puts it all together" you are essentially asking somebody else to do all of your work for you. And nobody will want to do that for free.

> I can see several things in the Android SDK/API that would let me do this

Fantastic, so you know where to start. Well why not just give it a try and attempt to integrate it yourself and get back to us if you get stuck on a specific detail. What I like to see before helping somebody is somebody that has [clearly tried to help themselves](http://ancienthistory.about.com/library/bl/bl_aesop_hercules_wagoner.htm). Tried and failed maybe; but still tried.

And perhaps [read this](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Robert, I am pretty sure I understand where you are coming from. I suppose I could have pointed out I have built Android Apps before (http://slideme.org/application/mars-lander), and been more specific on why this particular combination is confusing the heck out of me. But I was trying to be fairly generic since I have known other folks in the community who are looking for a similar tutorial if one exists. Obviously I was mistaken thinking this was the place to ask the question, and will go elsewhere. My apologies for wasting your time.